# Firebase set() callback only shows sync errors, but not security rule errors?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

In reference to the [Firebase set() function](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/set.html), is there a way to detect if the set() failed due to security rule errors?

Sample code (receives `null`, indicating success, even if the set actually failed due to security rules):

```
locationRef.set('someValue', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The Firebase docs say that the callback only receives an error if *synchronization* has failed, but it would be useful get passed an error for security rules too. This way I can confidently tell a user that their data has been saved.

Is there any way to do this? I suppose it would useful for any read/write function with an onComplete callback.

Comment: As a side note -- the only way "synchronization" can fail is if there is a security rule violation. Otherwise it's guaranteed to be successful -- eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of a security error, the error object will contain a PERMISSION_DENIED code:  http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/ZG9CY/

For instance, if I run the following against a protected path:

```
new Firebase(URL).set({ hello: 'world' }, function(error) {
    $('pre').text( 'done: '+ JSON.stringify(error) ); 
});
```

I get the following:

```
done: {"code":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}
```

<del>There is a doc somewhere talking about the error codes, when I find it I'll add it to this post.</del> (nope, [it's about authentication errors](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html))

Comment: Perfect. Wish I had enough rep to upvote your answer. Thanks!